# WPF Usercontrol WindowStartupLocation

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, window

How to get the `WindowStartupLocation` property of the `Window` in `UserControl`?

```
public partial class ActivityDetailsView : UserControl
{
    public ActivityDetailsView(ActivityDetailsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
        Loaded += ActivityDetailsView_Loaded;
        JobOrderLineItem.SelectionChanged += JobOrder_SelectionChanged;

        //this.WindowStartupLocation doesnt exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public partial class ActivityDetailsView : Window
{
    // ...
}
```

If your `UserControl` should behave like `Window` why not deriving from it?

Comment: Hmmm... I dont think I can do that.

Comment: Well it would be the easiest way. I don't understand why people are always inheriting from `UserControl` although they want to extend a `Window` or a `DataGrid`....